# Python: Using template and substitute in subroutine

Tags: python, substitution

I have a template file cotaining $DATE and $TIME to be substituted by the current values.
This works fine as long as I have evruthing in the main program.
However I want to put the substitution bit into a subroutine e.g. lie this:

```
def substitute():
  DATE = '20120209'
  TIME = '1200'
  f = open( 'template.txt' )
  template = string.Template( ''.join(f.readlines()) )
  f.close()

  # substitute and save

  f = open( 'current.txt', 'w+' )
  f.writelines(template.safe_substitute( globals() ))
  f.close()
```

As I said, this works fine if I have it in the main program. But in the def version it only works if DATE and TIME are already defined in the main program. Which I do dont want to do.

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: I don't understand. What you want to say with `DATE and TIME` ? The variables name, or variables value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `locals()` instead of `globals()` so the local values for `DATE` and `TIME` are substituted:

```
  f.writelines(template.safe_substitute( locals() ))
```

---

PS.

```
''.join(f.readlines())
```

is functionally equivalent to

```
f.read()
```

but slower since it splits the file into lines, then rejoins them. You might as well use `f.read()`.

Comment: Thanks that does the trick. I will also try your second suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a dictionary of your own like this:

```
subs = {'DATE' = '20120209',
        'TIME' = '1200'}

f.writelines(template.safe_substitute(subs))
```

`globals()` and `locals()` contain more than `DATE` and `TIME`.